# Is it possible to configure seprate port for admin webservices in spring boot using properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to configure 2 port in a single spring boot Application 
- one port is for normal user and second port is for admin web servies and console.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot provides two set of port, server port and management port.
Here is the [link](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/15/Configuring-Tomcat-to-Listen-on-Multiple-ports-using-Spring-Boot.html) to a blog which can be useful

Comment: I think management port and management context path is not to expose our web services